# Notification sound not working unless i manually give the permission for it in App info settings

Tags: java, android, notifications

**First, i tried to use the default notification sound but that too didn't work, so I jump on to custom notification tune but the same happened there. But when I gave manually "allow notification sound permission in-app info setting it worked fine".
can you guys see any problem?**
Here is my code:

```
   private void createNotificationChannel() {
        Uri sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.tune);
        AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .build();


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            NotificationChannel channel2 = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID_FOR_DELETE_OR_NOT,
                    utilityClass.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME_SECOND, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            channel2.enableVibration(true);
            channel2.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{300, 300, 300});
            channel2.shouldShowLights();
            channel2.canBypassDnd();
            channel2.setShowBadge(true);
            channel2.enableLights(true);
            channel2.setSound(sound, attributes);

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }



   Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID_FOR_DELETE_OR_NOT)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_bookmark_border_24)
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(""))
              .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.tune))
            .setDefaults(DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_baseline_bookmark_border_24, "Mark?", pendingIntent).build();
```

My manifest permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: There is a catch: if you previously configured notifications to be without a sound - they will be without a sound until the user manually allows it. It prevents app developers from abusing notification system by constantly enabling the sound. Are you sure you haven't previously turned off the sound? One thing you could do to test if your configuration is correct is to delete the application from a device and install it again. All of the push notification settings will be re-created based on what you wrote in `createNotificationChannel`.

Comment: Try to modify Uri creation to: `Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/tune.mp3");`. "mp3" extension of a file may be different.

Comment: thanks for response @JeneaVranceanu, but when i uninstall the app and reinstall it again, it still remains on the same settings which I gave it previously. e.g. if I turned off all the notification-related check box's it will show up the same thing after reinstalling it. Is there any way to completely uninstall the app with its saved settings

Comment: I'm having the same issue (with Xiaomi) .. if your device is Xiaomi - seems like in some devices the solution is only manually. programmatically open the app settings page and hope the user will understand to switch on the "allowed sound".